# Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality, sentence-usage

I have found two opposite views about the following sentence here : https://tinyurl.com/y7dvc48l

> "I love it very much."

One view is that this sentence is incorrect because you either love something or you don't. There are no degrees of love.

Another view is that this sentence is grammatically correct because love is emotional, and it is subjective, so you can have degrees of love.

Is it correct to say *"I love it very much"*?

Answer (score -1):

Degrees of love can be found everywhere in literature.  I love you too much, I love you so much, endless examples.  I imagine your link (I was not tempted to click) is some sort of pure logic treatment in the philosophy of love, but that does not mean you can`t have degrees of love in written prose.

Comment: Is it correct to say, "I love it very much"?